# Error with all pages in languages sails js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

My problem is that I do not keep the language on all my pages.
How can I do this? In Sails js

```
,'/:lang': {
         view: 'home/landing'
         ,policy: 'localize'
    }
```

But in the second page it does not maintain the language

```
module.exports = function(request, response, next){




 request.session.lang =request.param('lang');

console.log("=========================== El idioma que llega es '"+request.param('lang')+"'   {"+request.session.lang+"}")

request.setLocale(request.param('lang'));



next();
};
```